# PHP send form info to 2 different files

Tags: php, forms

I'm having a bit of a problem with a form. I need to send its information to 2 different pages for two different uses. One of the pages will show what was inserted in the form and the other one will use the form's title as a link to the other page.

The code I'm using is below. Right now, it only takes the form info and shows it in the View.php page.

I'm pretty sure I'll have to use some PHP in here, but I'm out of ideas.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>!!!!Protótipo de Formulario de Noticia!!!!</title>

    <style>
        textarea{
            resize:none;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="View.php">
        <p>Titulo: <input type="text" name="Titulo" required/></p>
        <p>Digite o texto da noticia abaixo:</p>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="Noticia" required></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Publicar" onsubmit="location.href='View.php;'" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need

```
onsubmit="location.href='View.php;'
```

The simplest approach is to submit to one page, which acts as a controller.  It can process the data, and selects a template for displaying the next page.

If needed, you can also pass data across pages with either a session, or http query params (url?id=1234)

Comment: the onsubmit is used to send the user to the view page to  see what he did in the form, but thanks alot.

Comment: action="View.php" will handle this part